# Bottom nav bar is not getting transparent in flutter

Tags: flutter, transparency, blur, flutter-bottomnavigation

My implementation of bottom nav bar in flutter is not getting transparent when I am using Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2), I am applying transparency to my nav bar because later I want to use backdrop filter to apply guassion blurr on it. However it is not getting transparent.

```
Scaffold(
      drawer: DrawerReskined(
        drawerItems: drawerItems,
      ),
      key: drawerKey,
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      extendBody: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        elevation: 0.0,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
        iconSize: 30,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          Provider.of<NavigationBarModel>(context, listen: false).setSelectedIndex(index);
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Column(
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/svg/home.svg",
                    width: 19,
                    height: 20,
                    color: _currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.blue : ProjectColors.fireFly,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/svg/selected.svg",
                    color: _currentIndex == 0 ? ProjectColors.warning : Colors.white,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              label: ''),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Column(
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/svg/on_going.svg",
                    color: _currentIndex == 1 ? Colors.blue : ProjectColors.fireFly,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/svg/selected.svg",
                    color: _currentIndex == 1 ? ProjectColors.warning : Colors.white,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              label: ''),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 45,
                height: 45,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: isTemplatesLoading
                      ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )
                      : Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() => isTemplatesLoading = true);
                    Boxes.addAllTemplate(await TemplateCorba.templates());
                    setState(() => isTemplatesLoading = false);
                    AddTemplateRoles.show(
                      context,
                      AddTemplate(position: _floatingButtonKey.getOffset),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            label: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Column(
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/svg/business_overview.svg",
                    color: _currentIndex == 3 ? Colors.blue : ProjectColors.fireFly,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/svg/selected.svg",
                    color: _currentIndex == 3 ? ProjectColors.warning : Colors.white,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              label: ''),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Column(
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/svg/profile.svg",
                    color: _currentIndex == 4 ? Colors.blue : ProjectColors.fireFly,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/svg/selected.svg",
                    color: _currentIndex == 4 ? ProjectColors.warning : Colors.white,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              label: ''),
        ],
      ),
    ))
```

also it would be helpful if someone suggest good ways to apply backdrop filter for guasion blur.

Comment: Have you tried using a hexadecimal color code?

Comment: yes I have, still nothing. It seems it is not applying transparency whatever I do that's why I have to ask here.

Comment: below is correct and working answer

Comment: I had the same issue and i think i've figured it out. apparently the SafeArea widget doesn't allow the extendBody widget to work properly so removing from the scaffold's child fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your bottom navigation bar in a theme data and aligning it at the bottom-center

```
...
bottomNavigationBar: Align(
alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Theme(
                    data: Theme.of(context)
                        .copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),///Try this
                       child: BottomNavigationBar()
...
```

Comment: not working it just remove every thing from screen.

Comment: Make sure you are wrapping the Align widget on the correct widget

Answer (score 0):

Its working on me are you sure it is not transparent??

```
class DemoView extends StatelessWidget {
  const DemoView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: List.generate(
              20,
              (index) => Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    child: ListTile(
                      tileColor:
                          index & 1 == 1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.deepPurple,
                      title: Text(
                        'Item $index',
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
        ),
      ),
      extendBody: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Colors.teal,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
        useLegacyColorScheme: false,
        elevation: 0,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.place), label: 'place'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.book), label: 'book'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]